# Recreate Database Schema-Only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to make a process for recreating a database schema-only. Not a backup/restore but standing up a schema-only copy of a database on a different server, that we would populate with data manually. I was thinking about using SMO in powershell. Does anyone know what the best approach for this would be? Prefer to stay away from 3rd party options, I have the time to do it myself.

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to script out all the tables, procs, jobs, etc or just a subset of these or...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `DBCC CLONEDATABASE`(structures + statistics):

1. `DBCC CLONEDATABASE('original_db_name', 'cloned_db')`
2. `ALTER DATABASE [cloned_db] SET READ_WRITE WITH NO_WAIT`
3. Backup
4. Restore on second server
5. `ALTER DATABASE [cloned_db] MODIFY NAME = original_db_name`;

Comment: This may work! I wasn't aware of this function. Thank you!